# How do you replace componentWillReceiveProps when there is a context parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, upgrade, react-component

In react, the standard way to replace `componentWillReceiveProps` is to use either `getDerivedStateFromProps` or `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` along with `componentDidUpdate`. How do you do this replacement when `componentWillReceiveProps` has a second parameter- context, and you need properties in it?

For example, let's say the code is like this-

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, context) {
     if (context.href !== this.context.href) {
          const parsedUrl = url.parse(context.href, true);
          const from = parseInt(parsedUrl.query.from, 100) || 0;
          this.setState({
            from,
            more: [],
           });
     }
}
```

Most examples online showing migration from `componentWillReceiveProps` 
to either `getDerivedStateFromProp` or `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` do not have the parameter `componentWillReceiveProps'` `context` parameter. Neither `getDerivedStateFromProp` nor `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` have `nextContext`. So, how is `context` dealt with during the migration?

Comment: Can you show the code your are trying to update.

Comment: @MkeSpaGuy- Added sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I am still investigating. So far, the answer seems to be to migrate to the next context API method of getting context- https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. Tania wrote a nice tutorial on the topic- https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/